# get num_rows and result() data in same function on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hı,
how can ı return get result data and result num rows in same functions 
ı try with this function but it is not run

```
    $user_id=$this->session->user_sess['id'];
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('uto', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('isread','0');
    $this->db->from('user_messages');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $q['id']=$query->result();
    $q['data']=$query->num_rows();
   return $q;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you trying to access the returned data in the controller?

Comment: have you checked with `print_r($q)` if you have a result?

Comment: try to do more research and reconstruct your query and please also provide more details on what you are asking.

Comment: if you have result array then what is the use of num_row. you can use PHP functions count($q) or sizeof($q) to find no of rows in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user_id=$this->session->user_sess['id'];
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('uto', $user_id);
$this->db->where('isread','0');
$this->db->from('user_messages');
$query=$this->db->get();
$q['result']=$query->result();
$q['rows']=$query->num_rows();
return $q;
```

controller:

```
$result = $this->some_model->my_model_function();
$num_rows = $result['rows'];
$data = $result['result'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out...

```
 $user_id=$this->session->user_sess['id'];
 $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * from user_messages WHERE  uto = '".$user_id."' AND  isread = '0' ");
 return $query->num_rows();
```

hope that helps.

Comment: How does changing the query from qb format to a manual format solve the issue?

Comment: try to do more research and reconstruct your query ;) at least do this via binding, beside the fact as alex said - this query is less valuable than op's one...

Answer (score 0):

you may try with storing result set into two variable like : -

```
$query=$query1= $this->db->select('*')->from('table_name')->get();
echo $query->num_rows(); //number of rows
print_r($query1->result()); // result object
```

second approach by using result set object itself like :-

```
$query=$this->db->select('*')->from('table_name')->get();
echo $query->result_id->num_rows; //number of rows
print_r($query->result()); // result object
```